# Operator Overloading Python

Tags: python, set

Is it possible to implement a method of a class so that objects of it works with set() function? So Set(objarray) would return unique objects. Of course, creating my own set is an option, but I just don't want to reinvent the wheel if it is already there.

EDIT : I think I got your guys confused with my English. This is what I have in my class - I have a Person class that has person name and address as its members. This is what I want to do -

```
persons = []
for i in range (50):
  name = raw_input("Enter Name")
  address = raw_input("Address")
  persons.append(Person(name,address))
unique = Set(persons) #would only return one person from an address. 
                      #The rest from the same address will be removed
```

I hope that clear confusion.

Comment: Read your Title and Content once again.. How on Earth are they related??

Comment: Well, I presume it's related to operator overloading cuz Set method works on dictionary and I want my class to act like a dictionary.

Comment: He's probably wanting to overload the equality test.

Comment: Post some code...it's not exactly clear what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. First, if your class implements neither `__hash__` nor `__eq__`, then they are already hashable (the `id` is used as the hash value and comparisons are done by `is`).

Or, if you implement `__hash__` and `__eq__`, then your class instances can be safely used in a set or as dictionary keys:

```
>>> class Foo:
...     def __init__(self, val): self.val = val
...     def __hash__(self): return hash(self.val)
...     def __eq__(self, other): return self.val == other.val
...     def __repr__(self): return 'Foo(%r)' % self.val
... 
>>> print set([Foo(3), Foo("bar")])
set([Foo(3), Foo('bar')])
```

If you want to be able to call `set` directly on instances of your class, overload `__iter__` so that the class instances appear to be iterable:

```
>>> class CharSeq:
...     def __init__(self, first, last):
...         self.first = ord(first)
...         self.last = ord(last)
...     def __iter__(self):
...         return (chr(i) for i in xrange(self.first, self.last+1))
... 
>>> set(CharSeq('a', 'c'))
set(['a', 'c', 'b'])
```

Comment: I think he wants to do `set(Foo(3))`

Comment: His comments suggest that, but the original question suggests otherwise...ah, I'll just put both interpretations in the answer. Thanks.

Comment: It is always good to link the official docs - as there are some corner-cases  that might be interesting to check. http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__

Comment: Works like a charm, Thanks! But I don't understand what hashing does here. Isn't it all about equality testing and implementing __eq__ method shouldn't be enough? Many thanks

Comment: Objects in sets must be hashable; that's how sets can achieve high performance (if there was no hashing requirement, the sets would have to fall back to linear or binary search). Therefore, for efficiency, Python mandates that dictionary keys and set elements must be hashable.